# Laravel - DB::TABLE SQL - how to get join data in one queries

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, join

I Have 2 tables first client_group with data like below

[image]

second table client

[image]

in Controller I have code like below:

```
$client = DB::table('client_group')
                ->where('client_group.user_id','=',$user_id)
                ->join('client','client_group.client_id','=','client.id')
                ->select('client_group.*',
                 'client.client_email',
                )->get();
                
return view('client.group', ['client'=>$client]);
```

From this query i have results like below:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1278 ▼
#items: array:2 [▼
0 => {#1188 ▼
  +"id": 1
  +"groupname": "testowa grupa"
  +"user_id": 2
  +"client_id": "4,5,6"
  +"created_at": "2021-02-08 13:47:03"
  +"updated_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  +"client_email": "test1@wp.pl"
}
1 => {#1123 ▼
  +"id": 9
  +"groupname": "test2"
  +"user_id": 2
  +"client_id": "8,14,22"
  +"created_at": "2021-01-04 15:19:33"
  +"updated_at": null
  +"client_email": "test3@wp.pl"
}
]
}
```

client_id is always in one column ("client_id": "8,14,22") because is added like this.
Now is my question and issues,
how to change view and query to get insted of one email all clients emails? based on client_id, below current view.
At the moment I have only one email first from client_id lists

```
<td>{{ $row->groupname }}</td>
<td>{{ count(explode(',',$row->client_id)) }}</td>
<td>{{ $row->client_email }}</td>
```

[image]

Comment: `->join('client','client_group.client_id','=','client.id')` this has not to work, you join two tables by string and integer id, the storing client ids in one field is a bad way and will force a lot of troubles, you should use manyToMany relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all , use FIND_IN_SET to join table with comma separated values.
Something like this-

```
DB::table('client_group')
->where('client_group.user_id','=',$user_id)                
->join('client',\DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET(client.id,  
  client_group.client_id)"),">",\DB::raw("'0'"))
->select('client_group.*', \DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(client.client_email) 
  as client_emails"))
->get();
```

And in the blade file you can get client emails like this-
{{ $row->client_emails }}

Comment: it works, thx groupBy was also required but it works as should be, Thanks